# Error loading SVG - ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: nginx, svg, decoding, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have a server running Nginx with the Google Pagespeed module installed.

Up until recently, I had no issues with SVGs on my website, however now Chrome is giving me the error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

The image is located in: /images/bg.svg

Manually loading the image with a random query parameter ie. bg.svg?v=2 loads the SVG normally without errors so perhaps it's a caching issue.

How can I go about troubleshooting this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the discussion behind this link
https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/issues/1346

Same error is discussed as a ngx_pagespeed issue. Solution that worked for me was adding this to my nginx config:

```
pagespeed Disallow "*.svg";
```

More info about it:
https://modpagespeed.com/doc/restricting_urls

Comment: also u need clear pagespeed cache
rm -rf /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache/* && nginx -s reload